# CSS Flex how to make dynamic grid

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a dynamic grid system for my product cards images, but I can't figure it out.

**I need this layout depending on the number of images the product has. The problem is the child items are images and won't crop.**

[image]

**I tried with Flex but I can't make the images crop.**

**HTML**

```
  <div class="kit-product-card">
  <div class="kit-image-container">
    <% kit.products.each do |kit_product| %>
    <div>
      <img src="test.png">
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  </div>
```

**¿Any ideas? Maybe playing with `overflow:hidden` + nth-childs?  Thanks a lot!**

**CSS**

```
.kit-product-card {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid darken(#f7f8fd, 4%);
}

.kit-image-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* enable the wrap */
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  div {
    flex-basis: 50%; /* width = 50% */
    flex-grow: 1; /* grow if alone in the last row */
    border: 1px solid white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

Comment: There is no way for CSS to know how many child elements a container has. CSS is a read-only language and as such does not check the HTML markup. You either need to hard-code a class that applies those changes or you need JS to count the child elements and apply a class for the case.

Comment: I'm using a Ruby conditional to know the number of child items. I just need to figure out CSS rules depending on the number of items output given by my conditional.

Comment: ok  is it possible for you to add a class then to the container depending on the amount of the child items? and last, can it be more then 6 child or is 6 the absolute max?

Comment: It's possible yes, I can add a class to it! 8 would be the max items! I was wondering if there is an "automatic" way without hardcoding classes with flexbox.

Comment: alright great, give me 15-30 minutes, I get a working snippet to show how to solve it with CSS.

Comment: When you say that you can't get the images to crop I assume your issue is that you need to add `width: 100%` to the img tag. Maybe you should also use some form of the [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) property. But you would really be much better off using CSS grid over flex for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

As already said in the comment, I would add a class to the container that defines the amount of child elements. You can do this with Ruby conditional (I just did it with JS in the example).

Then you sue Flexbox and define the with of the child div depending on the amount of child elements (as set through the class). To fit the image you can use `object-fit: cover` on the image:

```js
// JS code just for demonstration purpose
var input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var amount = input.value;
  var container = document.querySelector('.kit-image-container');
  container.innerHTML = '';
  var class_name = '';
  for (let i = 1; i <= amount; i++) {
    let ele = document.createElement('div');
    ele.innerHTML = '<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.jpg">';
    container.appendChild(ele);
    class_name = `child-${i}`;
  }
  container.className = '';
  container.classList.add('kit-image-container', class_name);
})
```

```css
.kit-image-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.kit-image-container > div {
  width: 100%;
}

.child-4 > div,
.child-5 > div,
.child-6 > div,
.child-7 > div,
.child-8 > div {
  width: 50%;
}

.child-3 > div:nth-last-of-type(-n+2) {
  width: 50%;
}

.child-6 > div {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
}

.child-5 > div:nth-last-of-type(-n+3),
.child-7 > div:nth-last-of-type(-n+3),
.child-8 > div:nth-last-of-type(-n+3) {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
}

.child-8 > div:nth-last-of-type(-n+6) {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
}

.kit-image-container > div > img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}




/* for visualization only */
.kit-image-container {
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.kit-image-container > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" min="1" max="8" step="1" value="1">
<label>Define the amount of child element</label>


<!-- actual Markup -->
<div class="kit-image-container child-3"></div>
```